# Генерация значений selectpicker из struct

Tags: mysql, golang

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
<select name="id_group" class="form-control selectpicker" value="{{.Name}}" required>
<option value="">Выберите группу</option>
{{- /*gotype: invbase.Group*/ -}}
{{range .}}
<option> {{.Name}}</option>
{{end}}
</select>
</div>
```

Есть вот такой код, который должен выводить список групп для выбора. Значения Group заполняются из mysql (вывод в консоль есть). Но строки выбора не генерируются. Подскажите что делаю не так - изучаю Golang только вторую неделю.

И еще вопрос: будет выбрано .Name, но мне надо в базу записывать .Id, которое будет соответствовать этому .Name. Можно как-то назад в go из selectpicker передавать вместо .Name соответствующий ему .id или придется потом поиск по базе делать?

Answer (score 0):

Другой вопрос в продолжение:

```
data := struct {
        users []User
        groups []Group
        cabinets []Cabinet
        documents []Document
    }{users, groups, cabinets, documents}

tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("templates/asset/create.html")
tmpl.Execute(w, data)
```

в HTML

```
<select name="id_group" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
<option value="">Выберите группу</option>
{{range .groups}}
<option>{{.Name}}</option>
{{end}}
</select>
```

Вроде правильно вызываю, но select не формируется.
Как правильно вызвать массив?